# Using find to find a file with a certain name and contents

Tags: grep, find

I am new to Linux. I am trying to find a file called `start.sh`, start searching from `/` and suppress any errors. At the same time, the file should also contain a variable called `sys_home`.

Please let me know if this is correct:

```
find / -name start.sh | grep "sys_home" *
```

Comment: How would you tell the `sys_home` string, used as a variable, apart from the same string used in an error message, or in some other context where it's not a variable?

Comment: This question is now much better, and you show something of what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

If you're piping (`|`) to `grep`, it reads from `stdin`, so you won't need to add that filenames argument (`*`):

```
find / -name start.sh | grep "sys_home"
```

However, this won't work as you expect! `find` will output a list of names, and your `grep` will try to match `sys_home` in this list, not in the content of the files!

---

You need to use `find` with `-exec` (alternative `xargs`):

```
find / -name 'start.sh' -exec grep -q 'sys_home' {} \; -print
```

Add `2>/dev/null` to suppress error messages

```
find / -name 'start.sh' -exec grep -q 'sys_home' {} \; -print 2>/dev/null
```

---

As an alternative, you could also directly use `grep` in recursive mode (`r`) which I think is easier:

```
grep -rls 'sys_home' --include='start.sh' /
```

- `-r` Recursive mode
- `--include='start.sh'` Find only files matching the glob pattern `start.sh`
- `-l` Only print filenames, not the matching line
- `-s` Suppress error messages

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing it up